# Xcode Helper does not have the accessibility permissions needed to run tests

Tags: macos, xcode, accessibility

I am getting this error when attempting to run some accessibility UTs on a project.  I was under the impression that a prompt such as this would appear:

[image]

However, I am not seeing this prompt.  I also tried to go to "Security & Privacy > Accessibility" to give the app "Xcode helper" the proper permissions, but I cannot find "Xcode helper" anywhere on my computer... only Xcode.  I added Xcode but am still hitting this error.  Ideas?  Where can I find "Xcode helper"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I find "Xcode helper"?

The Xcode Helper app is located inside the Xcode bundle:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/Xcode Helper
```

To get rid of the error message:

1. Open System Preferences.
2. Select Security & Privacy>Privacy>Accessibility. Unlock the panel, if necessary.
3. Press the "+" button, navigate to:
   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents`

add the Xcode Helper app and press Open:

[image]

5. Enable it:

[image]